# Pasting Copied image in Microsoft Word as Picture reduces its resolution

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, images, copy-paste, microsoft

Whenever I try to copy an image in my Word document and paste it elsewhere in the Word document, if I chose paste option as Picture (U), the pasted image's resolution gets lowered.

Can it be prevented by any settings?

See here:

[image: Diagram depicting the issue]

Comment: Your problem is using Paste As Image. Don't do that. If you use the "normal" copy+paste within a document then it should simply link to the original image in the document. You can change the default paste settings if it is not doing what you want by default https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/control-the-formatting-when-you-paste-text-20156a41-520e-48a6-8680-fb9ce15bf3d6

Answer (score 2):

There is a setting in Options that is important to preserving image quality in Word.

Navigate to: Options | Advanced | Image Size and Quality.

From there, select the default resolution for all your documents or the particular document you're working on.

You can also select "Do not compress images in file" to prevent Word from compressing the images when you close the file.  See the picture below:

[image: Microsoft Word Advanced Options]

Answer (score -1):

Preserving the original formatting while copying may solve the problem (usually the first option for pasting)